# No international patent

Tags: international, us20020187719

I am from South Africa, and I want to import something to the markets here.

I have found a patent on it, but not sure if it applies to the international market, it sure does not look like it.I could not find any documentations that with regards to an international patent.
Patent number is US20020187719

I certainly do not want to be guilty of infringment....

I know they have an international trademark... but If I change the name, can I import/manufacture it here?

Comment: Can you clarify -- do you want import the product into South Africa or do you want to export it to the US?

Answer (score 1):

I asked for some clarification above.

With regard to the particular patent application above, the invention has been patented in the US as [Patent No. 6666740](http://www.google.com.ar/patents/US6666740). The inventor does not appear to have obtained any patents outside of the US. [Link to ESPACE FAMILY SEARCH](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/searchResults?compact=false&ST=singleline&query=09264294&locale=en_EP&DB=worldwide.espacenet.com). You won't be infringing the US patent as long as you don't make/use/sell/import any of the toys into the US.

I don't know if you are planning to make a direct knock-off version of an existing product. But, if so, there may also be some legal issues stemming from trademark and counterfeiting law.